# Is $(y,T)=(7,8)$ the only solution in positive integers to $\frac{F(y)}{F(T)}=\frac12$, where $F(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Define $F(x)=x\cdot(x-1)\cdot(x-2)\cdot(x-3)$. Let $y,T$ be positive integers. Is it then true that $y=7$, $T=8$ is the only solution to this equation?
> $$\frac{F(y)}{F(T)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

**Motivation for the question:**

The motivation for the question comes from this exercise:

> Assume you have a bag with green and red balls. You pick 4 balls at
> random, all of them are green. You are told that the probability for
> this to happen is $0.5$. How many green balls were there in the bag,
> and how many balls were there in total?

By trial and error it can be shown that $7$ green balls and $1$ red ball, 8 in total will solve this probability exercise. But I am wondering if this is the only possibility? Or are there other combinations of green and red balls that would work? If the answer to the original question is yes, then only green = 7, total = 8 would work.

Is there a way to show that no other possibility would work?

PS: I don't know much about number theory, those tags was edited in. But I understand the answer may lie in that category of mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *hint*: Note that
$$
F(n)+1=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) + 1 = (n^2 + 3n + 1)^2.
$$
So the equation $2F(n)=F(m)$ is equivalent to
$$
2(n^2+3n+1)^2-(m^2+3m+1)^2=1.
$$
This is a (negative) Pell equation. From its solutions we can deduce the solutions of the original equation.

Edit: On needs to rewrite the four consecutive numbers in the product, i.e., $n=x-3$.

Comment: You still have the problem that when examining the solutions $(x=1,y=1), (x=5,y=7), ...$ you still have to determine which of these solutions may be expressible as $(x = n^2 + 3n + 1, y = m^2 + 3m + 1).$  For example, based on this criteria, I think that you would have to reject both $(x=1,y=1)$ and $(x=5,y=7).$

Comment: As I see it, since the complete list of solutions to your variation of the Pell Equation is $(\sqrt{2} + 1)(2\sqrt{2} + 3)^n = (y + x\sqrt{2})$, some way is needed to tie the resultant $y,x$ to $(m^2 + 3m + 1, n^2 + 3n + 1).$

Comment: For what it's worth, the next solution after $(x = 5, y = 7)$ is $(x = 29 = 4^2 + [3\times 4] + 1, y = 41 = 5^2 + [3\times 5] + 1).$  Following the OP's syntax, this leads to $\frac{F(7)}{F(8)} = \frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Yes, this looks good. I think, the hint is not really worth a downvote.

Comment: Astonished that anyone would downvote your answer.  Certainly, I did not.  In fact, I just upvoted it.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you! Also for your good comments.